# Price for simultaneous database connection in firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, price

document on homepage says only 200,000 per database.

but what is it? how much would they charge me. hen simultaneous connection occurs 100,000?
no mention for simultaneous connection on calculator.

Comment: Are you aware how ridiculously large 200k connections are? I mean, I can run a website with 100.000 concurrent users on less than 100 connections. 200k CONCURRENT connections is RIDICULOUS out of anything. There is no mention because this is possibly a hard limit and it is WAY out of realistic.

Comment: Agree with @TomTom . You won't possibly reach that limit unless you're offering GTA V for free.

Comment: Even then likely not. Point is that best practices are to only keep connections OPEN when they are DIRECTLY in use - and let pooling handle the overhead. This brutally takes down the amount of concurrent connections. Also, there is an overhead. 200k connections, even at 10kb per connection, is 2.000.000kb memory use. Doubt that you can affort that ;) And yes, the server needs to reserve memory for the connection.

Answer (score 0):

While there are limits to the number of simultaneous connections that are allowed to each Firebase Realtime Database instance, there is no charge for this number of concurrent connections.

Charges are only based on the amount of data stored, and the amount of data that is downloaded out of the database.

Comment: Doesn't establishing connections incurs TLS handshake which is charged because of the data egress? It could be significant, something like $30 per million connections?

Comment: There is no specific charge for TLS, but establishing requires about 3½KB of bandwidth for the TLS handshake, which is charged as part of the amount of data that is downloaded out of the database.