# Limits for simultaneous connections Firebase

Tags: database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I am new with Firebase and I have heard that there is a limit for simultaneous connections.
My app doesn't require to store who is online at a specific moment, just some details about each account(name, picture, etc.). So, I do not know if those limitations will apply to this type of app or not. If they do, what is the limit? In a previous post somebody said it is 100,000 users, but on their documentation I have found something about 1,000,000 users (Maximum concurrent connections for mobile/web clients per database   1,000,000). Furthermore, there is no mention for simultaneous connection on their price calculator.
Also, if I have misunderstood anything about "simultaneous connections", please explain here.
Have a good day and thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no cost for simultaneous collections. See my answer to [Price for simultaneous database connection in firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62487071).

The Firebase Realtime Database allows up to 100 concurrent connections per project on its free plan, and up to 200,000 concurrent connections per database on its paid plans.

Cloud Firestore has no limit on the number of concurrent connections, neither on the free nor the paid plan.

These limits is regardless of the application type, and depends on how your code uses the database. Since you didn't share (and it seems didn't write) any code yet, it's hard to say more.

Comment: So if my app requires access to the database only when an user wants to see his/her profile(just name, age and a profile picture) and a leaderboard, there are no problems if let's say there are 1,000,001 users connected in the same time? Also if they do not access any of the mentioned above things, they can be unlimited users connected?

Comment: And what is the difference between cloud firestore and firebase database?

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rtdb-vs-firestore

Comment: On the connections: please read the comments question I linked, as having 1M concurrent/simultaneous connections is an **incredibly rare** occurrence.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot. But hypothetically speaking, this is possible. Just for my curiosity, how could this situation be handled? Sorry for insisting on the topic.

Comment: I mean I see that some apps have more than 1M users. Yes, I know that all of them can't connect simultaneous, but let's assume they can.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/sharding